# Recursive SQL with more tables

Tags: sql, recursion, recursive-query

I've a question about the use of recursive SQL in very particular situation which I describe below.

I have a table A with a **(ID, value)** schema and these sample rows:

```
(1,1000)
(2,800)
(3,300)
(4,600)
```

I have a table B with a **(ID, value)** schema and these sample rows:

```
(1,600)
(2,300)
(3,400)
(4,600)
(5,600)
(6,400)
```

The purpose is that I have to select the maximum ID from A and the maximum ID from B and then subtract from the value in A the value in B and produce a row for any operation like this one.

The final result should be a schema **(ID-A, ID-B, subtraction-value)** and the rows produced will be these ones:

```
(1,1,600) remains 400 in A.ID=1 and remains 0 in B.ID=1
(1,2,300) remains 100 in A.ID=1 and remains 0 in B.ID=2
(1,3,100) remains 0 in A.ID=1 and remains 300 in B.ID=3
(2,3,300) remains 500 in A.ID=2 and remains 0 in B.ID=3
(2,4,500) remains 0 in A.ID=2 and remains 100 in B.ID=4
(3,4,100) remains 200 in A.ID=3 and remains 0 in B.ID=4
(3,5,200) remains 0 in A.ID=3 and remains 400 in B.ID=5
(4,5,400) remains 200 in A.ID=4 and remains 0 in B.ID=5
(4,6,200) remains 0 in A.ID=4 and remains 200 in B.ID=6
```

At this point the rows in one of the tables are finished and I need to stop!

I don't know if this is possible with recursive SQL, for sure I think that I have to merge table A and B to produce a fixed table on which I can do my calculation and produce what I explained above, but I don't know how to manage the rests which I don't know a priori, for instance the values at time t depends on what has happened at t-1).

Do you have some advise, some links to help me understand if it's possible to manage this with recursive SQL?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: I think that what you are looking for can be achieved with a SELECT and JOINS between A and B.  The result set calculation is not clear for me though.  Can you express the result more mathematically?  E.g.(Id A, Id B, MAX(A Value)-Max(B Values) *??)

Comment: Let's say that table A is the source and table B are the values I have to subtract to A.

At every step I consider the value from the row in A that has the highest ID AND value > 0 and take the value from the row in B that has the highest ID AMD value > 0.
At this point I subtract from the value in A the value in B (or part of it, see below).
As you can see in the example above, if B.value<A.value then I do A.value-B.value and B.value will be 0, if B.value>A.value then I put A.value to 0 and B.value will be B.value-A.value and this remaining part will be considered in the following step.

Comment: @brokenp87 . . . You description says `max` but the example uses `min` on the ids.  You are doing a greedy algorithm to allocate the "B" values into the "A" buckets.  Interesting problem.  There may be an iterative solution.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was confused by ascending order...sorry...

Comment: @broken87 . . . Would a solution where you can split the buckets work for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently recursive about this process.  It is described as an iterative process and it is an iterative process.

You are assigning the B values to A, each in order, subject to a simple condition:  the sum of the Bs does not exceed the A value in each bucket.  You can do this with cursors, by setting up separate cursors on A and B.  Then proceed to do the assignment based on this simple rule.

I cannot think of a way to do this using set logic in SQL.  However, the iterative approach using cursors may be your best solution.